Combining MPI_Unpack() with an arithmetic operation
Suppose I'm going to read n double values from an input buffer with MPI_Unpack and add them to an already existing array of n doubles. The easy way and the only way I'm aware of is to create a temporary array as an intermediate buffer and first MPI_Unpack into the temporary array and then sum the two arrays.
I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way.
Two possibilities:

There exists a standard MPI function which combines MPI_Unpack and summation.
The input buffer can be processed prior to the call to MPI_Unpack (summation can be performed before calling MPI_Unpack.)

I haven't tried the 2nd possibility. Even if it works on my system I can't be sure it will work on any system. (e.g. on heterogeneous systems)

Do you really need to MPI_Pack() in the first place? If not, use MPI_Reduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, ...)
